# sqldriverconnect in c++ failed to connect to local database sql 2008

Tags: c++

can someone here kindly help?
I am trying to connect to sql server 2008 in c++ by using SqlDriverConnect. 
Here is my code:

```
SQLTCHAR *srv = (SQLTCHAR *) "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=bbData;Data Source=NBK-EMMAY";
SQLRETURN rc = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, srv, strlen((char*)srv),
                                (SQLWCHAR*)OutConnStr, 255, &OutConnStrLen, SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT);
```

Note, the srv string is created and verified by the .udl file. 
I have tried various options, but seems I can go nowhere. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Q: What's the error message?

Comment: the return code is -1, which is SQL_ERROR.

Comment: There are several ways to get the error, including SQLGetDiagRec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  But shf301 is correct: SqlDriverConnect() is an ODBC interface, and you're using a non-ODBC connection string.  Refer to the link I just cited for details.

Answer (score 6):

You using an OleDb connection string, not an ODBC connection string.  `SqlDriverConnect` in an ODBC function, it won't work with an OleDb provider.

Try using the following connection string:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=JBK-EMMAY;Database=bbData;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```